# How to count the rows from multiple tables in MYSQL and get a sum of it?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

1. Table 1 - table1_id, title
2. Table 2 - table2_id, table1_id
3. Table 3 - table3_id, table2_id

Here Table 2 has reference of Table 1 there can be multiple Table 2 rows referring Table 1 and Table 3 is referring to Table 2 there can be multiple Table 3 rows referring to Table 2.

There is an one-many relationship between Table1-Table2 and Table2-Table3

Now I want the sum of all the rows in Table 3 with table1_id

[image]

Input- table1_id = "abc"

Output- 9

PS- Sorry for such abstract description , its quite difficult to explain here if needed I can add some more details.

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: @fa06 Have added the table structure and sample data you can have a look

Comment: is it the sum or the count you need

Comment: i need the sum of all the counts of Table3 rows referring to Table2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t3.id), SUM(t3.amount)
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.table2_id
 GROUP BY t1.id
```